# All directory or list values getting updated with same value in python

Tags: python, directory, web-crawler, updates

**Background**

With Python, I am crawling a list of websites stored in a list, by iterating through the list. Each website URL is collected from the list and crawled through a function. The response of that function is returned and the crawled data is added to a directory.

**Problem**

Everytime a new response is returned from the crawling function call and the response is added to the dictionary, all values in the directory are updated with the latest value. I also tried adding the responses to the list and all values in the list are also getting updated with the latest response value.

**Debug tried**

I printed individual responses in each iterations before and after adding them to dictionary or list, and these responses were same before and after addition to directory or list, and differed in each iteration. It means the responses are coming distinct as per the expected behaviour. But the entire list gets updated with latest value.

**Code**

```
for jobListingPage in jobListingPages:
    try:
        r = urllib.urlopen(jobListingPage).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
        jobsSummaryMarkup = soup.find_all("h2", class_=["g-col10"])
        i = 0
        for jobSummaryMarkup in jobsSummaryMarkup:
            jobDetailsURL = base_url_sof+str(jobSummaryMarkup.a["href"])
            jobDetailsFindRes = find_job_details(jobDetailsURL)
            if(jobDetailsFindRes[0] == 0):
                #print("******crawled response before adding")
                #print(jobDetailsFindRes[1])
                i=i+1
                all_jobs_data["job "+str(i)] = jobDetailsFindRes[1]
                #print("******crawled response after adding")
                #print(jobDetailsFindRes[1])
                #print("******cumulative dictionary")
                #print(all_jobs_data)
                #print("###########################################")
        return([0, all_jobs_data])
    except Exception as e:
        return([-1, e])
```

**Output of above code**

The output after uncommenting the print statements, the following output is obtained.after three iterations, i.e., crawling three websites from the list..

```
******crawled response before adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['user-interface', 'html5', 'javascript', 'angularjs', 'reactjs'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/170630/ui-front-end-developer-citrix', 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior', ' Lead'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Frontend Developer'], 'company_name': 'Citrix', 'job_name': 'UI /Front-End Developer'}
******crawled response after adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['user-interface', 'html5', 'javascript', 'angularjs', 'reactjs'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/170630/ui-front-end-developer-citrix', 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior', ' Lead'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Frontend Developer'], 'company_name': 'Citrix', 'job_name': 'UI /Front-End Developer'}
******cumulative dictionary
{'job 1': {'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['user-interface', 'html5', 'javascript', 'angularjs', 'reactjs'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/170630/ui-front-end-developer-citrix', 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior', ' Lead'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Frontend Developer'], 'company_name': 'Citrix', 'job_name': 'UI /Front-End Developer'}}
#########################################
******crawled response before adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}
******crawled response after adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}
******cumulative dictionary
{'job 1': {'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}, 'job 2': {'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}}
#########################################
******crawled response before adding
{'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}
******crawled response after adding
{'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}
******cumulative dictionary
{'job 1': {'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}, 'job 2': {'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}, 'job 3': {'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}}
#########################################
```

The last item is transitive through the entire dictionary and update all items. The same happens if I append the last item to a list, entire list gets updated with last item.

How do I add distinct items to the dictionary instead of getting the entire directory updated by the same last item?

**Edit**: Adding the code version where response is appended to list rather than adding to a dictionary.

**Code**

```
for jobListingPage in jobListingPages:
    try:
        r = urllib.urlopen(jobListingPage).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
        jobsSummaryMarkup = soup.find_all("h2", class_=["g-col10"])
        for jobSummaryMarkup in jobsSummaryMarkup:
            jobDetailsURL = base_url_sof+str(jobSummaryMarkup.a["href"])
            jobDetailsFindRes = find_job_details(jobDetailsURL)
            if(jobDetailsFindRes[0] == 0):
                #print("******crawled response before adding")
                #print(jobDetailsFindRes[1])
                all_jobs_data_list.append(jobDetailsFindRes[1])
                #print("******crawled response after adding")
                #print(jobDetailsFindRes[1])
                #print("******cumulative list")
                #print(all_jobs_data_list)
                #print("###########################################")
        return([0, all_jobs_data])
    except Exception as e:
        return([-1, e])
```

**Output of the above code is:**

```
******crawled response before adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['user-interface', 'html5', 'javascript', 'angularjs', 'reactjs'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/170630/ui-front-end-developer-citrix', 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior', ' Lead'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Frontend Developer'], 'company_name': 'Citrix', 'job_name': 'UI /Front-End Developer'}
******crawled response after adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['user-interface', 'html5', 'javascript', 'angularjs', 'reactjs'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/170630/ui-front-end-developer-citrix', 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior', ' Lead'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Frontend Developer'], 'company_name': 'Citrix', 'job_name': 'UI /Front-End Developer'}
******cumulative dictionary
[{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['user-interface', 'html5', 'javascript', 'angularjs', 'reactjs'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/170630/ui-front-end-developer-citrix', 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior', ' Lead'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Frontend Developer'], 'company_name': 'Citrix', 'job_name': 'UI /Front-End Developer'}]
#########################################
******crawled response before adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}
******crawled response after adding
{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}
******cumulative dictionary
[{'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}, {'location_name': 'Bengaluru', 'tags': ['python', 'django', 'java'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay', 'Industry': ['Mobile Payments', ' POS', ' Retail'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['Full Stack Developer'], 'company_name': 'MishiPay', 'job_name': 'Full Stack Developer'}]
#########################################
******crawled response before adding
{'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}
******crawled response after adding
{'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}
******cumulative dictionary
[{'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}, {'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}, {'location_name': 'Hyderabad', 'tags': ['architecture', 'web-services', 'togaf', 'websecurity', 'bigdata'], 'job_url': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe', 'Industry': ['Financial Services', ' Financial Technology', ' Information Technology'], 'Experience level': ['Mid-Level', ' Senior'], 'Job type': ['Permanent'], 'Role': ['System Administrator'], 'company_name': 'Paysafe', 'job_name': 'Web Security Architect  in Fintech & Big Data'}]
#########################################
```

**Sample data for jobListingPages**:

```
['https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p&l=India&d=100&u=Km', 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=India&d=100&u=Km&sort=i&pg=2']
```

**Sample data for jobListingPages**:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/170630/ui-front-end-developer-citrix
http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/171885/full-stack-developer-mishipay
http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/168402/web-security-architect-in-fintech-big-data-paysafe
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input data for jobListingPages ?

Comment: Done. Check the edit on post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `i = 0` is the culprit. Please move it outside the outer for loop and try again. The job counter is getting reset at every URL element of the list and it updates the existing value of the same key (e.g: job 1)

Comment: Tried moving i=0 outside. Didnt help. Output remains same. Earlier I tried removing this i=0 and i++ thing by adding response to a list directly where no key is required. Still the last value was updating all existing values.

See the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I have no clue how it worked, but `all_jobs_data_list.append(str(jobDetailsFindRes[1]))` to the list instead of  `all_jobs_data_list.append(jobDetailsFindRes[1])` did the work for me.

Similarly, `all_jobs_data_list["job "+str(i)] = str(jobDetailsFindRes[1])` in place of `all_jobs_data_list["job "+str(i)] = jobDetailsFindRes[1]`
got the entries distinct.

Will appreciate if someone can explain this :)